# I am updating a child record in a parent record's before update, which directly changes a rollup summary field on parent record of that child record

Tags: apex, trigger, dml

This causes a SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER error. Is there a workaround for this type of scenario?

I have outlined the trigger and object situation below:

Object Info:
Parent | Fields: RollupStage__c, Stage__c

Child | Fields: Stage__c

Trigger Info:
Parent | When Stage__c on parent is updated to specific value, update all related children stages to the same value. This causes the rollupstage__c field to change on parent.

This then causes a SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER error.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by splitting the logic. I did the update of the child records in an after update.